# URLMapping works on Local, but not on Server

Tags: asp.net, web-config, url-mapping

Hey! I'm using VS2010 and on my local machine, using web.config to map one url to another works fine, using the  tag. However, as soon as I upload to the IIS6 server it doesn't work at all! Is there something about IIS6 that doesn't support this feature?

Thanks, any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: thnaks for the answer / that was an interesting link. but what about url-mapping? i just want to learn what was that solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS6 doesn't support the newest versions of .NET.  What .NET version is your project running under?

Check out this article to help get you started: [Configuring IIS 6.0 to Use the Correct Version of the .NET Framework](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783640%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: It's running under 2.0 on the server. Thanks for the link, but it should work under 2.0 on IIS6, right? It doesn't make any sense!